# Azure Virtual Machine - Can't access MySQL database

Tags: mysql, azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, database-connection

I did create and setup a virtual machine in Azure Portal to be my MySQL Server. At this moment I can remotelly access my database normally using PHPMyAdmin. However, trying to connect it using a PHP script or Virtual Studio code, I'm getting connection error.

My PHP script:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('valicon.brazilsouth.cloudapp.azure.com:3306', 'myuser', 'mypassword', 'mydatabase');

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
echo '<p>Connection OK '. $mysqli->host_info.'</p>';
echo '<p>Server '.$mysqli->server_info.'</p>';
$mysqli->close();
```

The error I'm getting:

> Connect Error (2002) A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

My connection string in web.config file (Visual Studio):

```
<add name="MySQLConnection" 
         providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
    connectionString="server=valicon.brazilsouth.cloudapp.azure.com; user id=myuser; Password=mypassword; database=mydatabase; SslMode=none" />
```

The error I'm getting:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the
>   specified MySQL hosts.

What am I missing? Why I can access and manager my database remotelly using PHPMyAdmin but can't connect it with PHP or ASP.NET project?

**UPDATE**

I add a connection rule to my Virtual Machine setup that opens the port 3306 to external connection. Now I'm getting another error from PHP script:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find out what the problem was. So, for who is interested, I will leave the answer here.

I was not beeing able to connect the database remotelly through PHP or ASP.NET code because the 'bind-address' variable in MySQL configuration was setted with 127.0.0.1 value. That means only localhost could connect.

So, commenting the line

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf file (Linux Ubuntu 18.04), I could open the connection to any IP address.

Since PHPMyAdmin runs locally, it could connect the database even with the 'bind-address' setted as 127.0.0.1.